# Can't figure out what's causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am getting seemingly random 500 Internal Server Error responses from Apache on our newly launched Rails 3.1 site. The error follows:

> [ pid=19441 thr=2888301424 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:822
>   time=2011-09-15 15:45:07.311 ]: The backend application (process
>   19550) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at
>   all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there
>   are crashing bugs in this application.

Sometimes I'm also seeing the following error:

> [ pid=5805 thr=75783560 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-09-15 16:02:19.471
>   ]: *** Exception PGError in application (SSL SYSCALL error: EOF
>   detected ) (process 5805, thread #):
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:276:in
>   `exec'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:276:in`
>   block in clear_cache!'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:275:in
>   `each_value'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:275:in`
>   clear_cache!'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:303:in
>   `disconnect!'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:202:in`
>   block in disconnect!'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:201:in
>   `each'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:201:in`
>   disconnect!'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:35:in
>   `block in disconnect_with_synchronization!'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:34:in
>   `disconnect_with_synchronization!'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:395:in`
>   block in clear_all_connections!'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:395:in
>   `each_value'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:395:in`
>   clear_all_connections!'
>           from
>   /app/oath/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in
>   `clear_all_connections!'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:398:in`
>   before_handling_requests'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:204:in
>   `start_request_handler'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in`
>   block in handle_spawn_application'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in
>   `safe_fork'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in`
>   handle_spawn_application'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in
>   `server_main_loop'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in`
>   start_synchronously'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in
>   `start'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in`
>   start'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in
>   `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in`
>   lookup_or_add'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in
>   `block in spawn_rack_application'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in`
>   block in synchronize'
>           from :10:in `synchronize'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in`
>   synchronize'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in
>   `spawn_rack_application'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in`
>   spawn_application'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in
>   `handle_spawn_application'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in`
>   server_main_loop'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in
>   `start_synchronously'
>           from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in`
>   '

The box is running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and Apache/2.2.14 with Rails 3.1, Passenger 3.0.9, and Rack 1.3.2.

This is a rather simple site and I've run out of ideas.

Comment: I'm going to answer to my own question.

As of this date, when running Rails 3.1 with Passenger, the PassengerSpawnMethod configuration variable needs to be set to "conservative". You can read more about this issue at http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=684.